# Run c++ script on server

Tags: php, apache

I have PHP script, which is requested by user. In this script I want to run C++ script(exe), but not wait until this script finishes(because this script does some post-process with data, which PHP doesn't care about). Is there anyway to do this on Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [php exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. Bear in mind the comment on the page about apache:

> When calling exec() from within an
>   apache php script, make sure to take
>   care of stdout, stderr and stdin (as
>   in the example below).

Comment: Thanks :)(I thought system is nearly the same as exec)

Comment: The difference is that system displays the output to the browser.